# How do you prove Let φ : R → S be a EPIMORPHISM of rings. Then the image of φ is isomorphic to the factor ring R/ ker φ

Tags: ring-theory

Below I have proved this question for a ring homomorphism.

MY QUESTION: How do you prove Let φ : R → S be a EPIMORPHISM of rings. Then the image of φ is isomorphic to the factor ring R/ ker φ

Let φ : R → S be a homomorphism of rings. Then the image of φ is isomorphic to the factor ring R/ ker φ

Proof:

Let I denote the kernel of φ, so I is a two-sided ideal of R. Define a function

φ ̄ : R/I → Imφ by:

φ ̄ (a + I) = φ(a) for a ∈ R.

1. φ ̄ is well-defined (i.e. the image of a + I does not depend on a choice of coset representative). Suppose that a + I = a1 + I for some a, a1 ∈ R. Then a−a1 ∈IbyLemma3.3.2. Henceφ(a−a1)=0S =φ(a)−φ(a1). Thus φ(a) = φ(a1 ) as required.
2. φ ̄ is a ring homomorphism.
   Suppose a + I, b + I are elements of R/I. Then

   ̄ φ((a +I) +(b +I))  = φ ̄ ((a +b) +I)

= φ(a+b)

= φ(a) + φ(b)

= φ ̄(a+I)+φ ̄(b+I).

So φ is additive. Also

̄ φ((a+I)(b+I)) = φ ̄(ab+I) = φ(ab)

= φ(a)φ(b)

= φ ̄(a+I)φ ̄(b+I)

3. φ ̄ is injective.
   Suppose a+I ∈ kerφ. Thenφ(a+I) = 0S soφ(a) = 0S. This means a ∈ ker φ, so a ∈ I. Then a + I = I = 0R + I, a + I is the zero element of R/I. Thus ker φ ̄ contains only the zero element of R/I
4. φ ̄ is surjective. 
   Let s∈Imφ. Thens=φ(r)for some r∈R. Thus s=φ(r+I)and every element of Imφ is the image under φ ̄ of some coset of I in R.

Thus φ ̄ : R/ ker φ −→ Imφ is a ring isomorphism, and Imφ is isomorphic to the factor ring R/ ker φ.

Comment: An epimorphism of rings is just a surjective homomorphism of rings, so you've already proven it. Note that in this case $\operatorname{Im} \varphi = S$.

Comment: Thank you I was just checking that I wasn't assuming that incorrectly @ÍgjøgnumMeg

Comment: Note that there are two different definitions of epimorphism in this context – on the one hand as a surjective ring homomorzhism, and on the other hand as an epimorphism in the category of rings, see for instance https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epimorphism.